# Por favor me ajuda a filtrar por categoria em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

tenho 2 tabelas , a tabela artigos e a tabela categoria_artigo no banco de dados, o que quero é o seguinte, que apareça todos os nomes das categorias cadastradas (ex CATEGORIA1, categoria2, etc) e ao clicar na categoria vai para um arquivo categoria.php onde nele exibe todas postagens da categoria que cliquei, independente da categoria clicada vai neste documento, poderiam me ajudar por favor  olha abaixo o codigo que fiz so aparece o nome e a ID da categoria, baseado nele me  completam o código e da categoria.php por gentileza ? cod abaixo =

```
<?php
                    $result_categoria = "SELECT * FROM artigos WHERE sts_situacoe_id=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
                    $resultado_categoria = mysqli_query($conn, $result_categoria);
                    ?>
                    <div class="p-3">
                        <h4>Categorias</h4>
                        <ol class="list-unstyled" data-categoria="comida">>

                            <?php
                            while($row_categoria = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_categoria)){
                                echo "<li><a href='".pg."/artigo/".$row_categoria['id']."'>".$row_categoria['nome']."</a></li>";
                            }
                            ?>

                        </ol>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

pode resolver essa questão passando o id da sua categoria via url com GET, e no seu arquivo categoria.php, validar e pegar o valor do GET que seria o id da categoria e realizar uma consulta na tabela artigos pegando todos os artigos dessa categoria que creio que seja sua chave estrangeira na tabela artigos.

Em...

```
<?php
     while($row_categoria = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_categoria)){
       echo "<li><a href='".pg."/artigo/".$row_categoria['id']."'>".$row_categoria['nome']."</a></li>";
     }
?>
```

Modifique o seu href para passar o parâmetro do GET dessa forma...

```
echo "<li><a href='".pg."/artigo/categoria.php?categoria=".$row_categoria['id']."'>".$row_categoria['nome']."</a></li>";
```

Feito isso vc já tem a possibilidade de validar isso em no arquivo, aqui estou considerando que sua consulta é realizada no próprio arquivo categoria.php, se essa validação for realizada em outro arquivo, a lógica é a mesma, só precisando alterar o local para onde vai mandar o GET para validação.
No arquivo categoria.php pegue o valor do parâmetro e realize a consulta a sua tabela dessa forma...

```
// verificar se o parâmetro GET existe e se não é vazio
if(isset($_GET['categoria']) && !empty($_GET['categoria'])){
   $id = $_GET['categoria'];
   //.... Query para realizar a consulta e listar os resultados
} else {
   //... parâmetro GET não foi setado ou é vazio, faça o que desejar como mostrar aviso ou redirecionar para outra página
}
```

Pronto isso deve resolver sua questão de forma simples.
Espero ter ajudado, bons estudos!

**EDIÇÃO:**

Leticia, vou mudar um pouco a forma como vc escreveu o seu, é a mesma coisa mas de forma diferente de se escrever no html o php, isso deixou mais legível e percebi que está concatenando ".pg". em seu condigo, sem o símbolo $, esse pg é uma constante global? Se for, apenas tire o $, segue a alteração...

```
<div class="p-3"> <h4>Categorias</h4> 
  <ol class="list-unstyled"> 
    <?php while($row_categoria = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_categoria)): ?>
    <li><a href='<?php echo $pg; ?>/artigo/categoria.php?categoria=<?php echo $row_categoria['id'] ?>' ><?php echo $row_categoria['nome']; ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ol>
<div>
```

Comment: Obrigada Junior pela ajuda, mas tentei aqui e esta dando erro, nao esta aparecendo nada de valores,quero que apareça nome das categorias , tentei ver mas nao consegui entrar o erro, fiz alguns testes e nao deu certo, .. pode ver para mim ? e sim a tabela artigos tem uma chave estrngeira artigo_categoria_id para pegar o valor da tabela categoria.

Comment: Poderia dar um print_r($resultado_categoria) para que eu possa ajudar vc melhor.

Comment: editei la, eu que adicionei sem querer o >.. oops! 
mas arrumando esta aparecendo nada de resultado. alterei minha pergunta acima, pq errei do > haha desculpe

Comment: <?php
                        $result_categoria = "SELECT * FROM artigos WHERE sts_situacoe_id=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
                        $resultado_categoria = mysqli_query($conn, $result_categoria);
                        ?>

Comment: <div class="p-3">
                            <h4>Categorias</h4>
                            <ol class="list-unstyled">
                               
                                <?php
                                while($row_categoria = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_categoria)){
                                 echo "<li><a href='".pg."/artigo/categoria.php?categoria=".$row_categoria['id']."'>".$row_categoria['nome']."</a></li>";

Comment: }
                                ?>
                            
                            </ol>
                        </div>

Comment: Leticia, coloque esse print_r no post editando ele.

Comment: ?php
$result_categoria = "SELECT * FROM artigos WHERE sts_situacoe_id=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
$resultado_categoria = mysqli_query($conn, $result_categoria);
?>
<div class="p-3">
<h4>Categorias</h4>
<ol class="list-unstyled">
<?php
while($row_categoria = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_categoria)){
echo "<li><a href='".pg."/artigo/categoria.php?categoria=".$row_categoria['id']."'>".$row_categoria['nome']."</a></li>";
}
?>
</ol>
</div>

Comment: pronto cod completo acima

Comment: Editei a minha resposta com as correções que julguei necessárias.

Comment: pena que nao da pra conversar por chat Junior, agora apareceu as categorias uhuhu, mas esta dando pagina nao encontrada agora no categoria.php <- como se nao existisse ouch! se eu aprender isso consigo fazer e terminar o restante do projeto, praticamente so isso que falta oh gosh! vou ter que sair agora, amanha continuo, mas se souber o motivo e puder avisar agradeço muitooooo

Comment: Se a página não é encontrada, é preciso que verifique o caminho até ela no href, inspecione o seu código nas <li> e veja o que mostra no href delas, analise para ver onde está o erro, caso prefira, copie o caminho e cole na url no navegador e veja se a página abre.

Comment: Bom dia Junior, consegui na url direcionar na pagina tirei o $ antes do pg e o categoria=, direciona porem nao esta exibindo os posts, dentro da query no categoria.php coloquei para exibição normal, porem nada. ah desculpa o trabalho, se quiser desistir de me ajudar tudo bem eu entenderei, pior que depois que aprende se fala "puutz tão simples assim" tinha coisas que eu demorei depois que aprendi ficou super facil... este ai estou sofrendo

Comment: verifique se sua query está trazendo resultados, verifique que valor aprece na variável do GET, vc está tratando possíveis erros na em sua query? se não estiver, imprima a string da sua query, copie e no phpmyadmin vá na tabela e faça uma SQL com sua query e veja o que o painel do phpmyadmin lhe dá como resposta.